# Display a countdown timer in TKinter while making the code BLOCKING but do not freeze the GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

Please read my question carefully - I know there are plenty of ways to implement a countdown timer on Tkinter without freezing the window, but all of the existing solutions also cause the code to be non-blocking. For my use case, I need to schedule a task to run automatically after time's up while keeping the GUI active (not frozen). My guess is that I need to somehow block the execution of the next task, but that will also freeze the GUI window. So is there any way out?

What I have so far:

```
root = Tk.Tk()
def countdown(time, msg='Counting down'):
    def tick():
        nonlocal time
        status(f'{msg} ({60 - time}sec)')
        time += 1
    root.after(1000, tick)
```

where `status()` is simply a function that updates the text of some buttons.
The current count down function does not work by itself as I don't have a way to stop the `after()` after the timeout period.

The other parts of the program will be like:

```
countdown(10)  # I need this line to be blocking or somehow prevents the code from going to next line
print('starting scheduled job...')
job()
```

I have tried to use threading but as I said earlier on, this causes the code to be non-blocking, and the moment I use Thread.join(), the entire GUI freezes again.

Comment: What do you mean by "blocking" in this context? If a function blocks the event loop, your window WILL freeze.

Comment: use `threading` and place the countdown time in the other thread (don't use `.after` tho in that thread) along with the task. have the timer be a simple loop that will simply block the thing, then use a queue or some other global object to transfer data from the thread to main thread and upadte label there

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (but not your whole program) and I'm sure someone can show you how to do what you want.

Comment: @WilliamBradley What i meant was that it prevents the next line from executing, but of course I am look  for ways that will not block the main event loop

Comment: @Matiiss I have already tried that. What happens is no matter how I code the count down function, it will not block the execution in the main thread, causing the scheduled job to be run immediately after the timer starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your question doesn't make a lot of sense to me. From what I understand you want your `job()` function to be called after the countdown.

Using thread for this is unnecessary. You can just use after and once the timer reaches 0 call the `job()` function.

Here is a minimal example

```py
import tkinter as tk


def job():
    status.config(text="starting job")


def countdown(time, msg='Counting down'):
    
    time -= 1
    status.config(text=f'{msg} ({time}sec)')

    if time != 0:
        root.after(1000, countdown, time)

    else:
        job()  # if job is blocking then create a thread


root = tk.Tk()

status = tk.Label(root)
status.pack()

countdown(20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfectly solved my problem and simply to understand, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note: I may have overthought this and the other answer may actually be simpler perhaps

From my understanding you want to create a program that will after a certain time run another task, but neither the task, nor countdown should interfere with the GUI (but the task must run only after countdown), explanation in code comments:

```py
# import what is needed
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue, Empty
import time


# the function that the button will call to start the countdown
# and after that the task
def start_countdown():
    # disable button so not to accidentally run the task again
    # before it has even started
    button.config(state='disabled')
    # create a queue object
    queue = Queue()
    update_label(queue)
    # set daemon=True to kill thread if the main thread exits
    Thread(target=countdown, args=(queue, ), daemon=True).start()


# the task you want to do after countdown
def do_task():
    for _ in range(10):
        print('doing task...')
        time.sleep(0.5)


# the actual countdown (btw using `time.sleep()` is more precise
# and only the thread will sleep)
# put data in queue so that it can easily be accessed
# from the main thread
def countdown(queue):
    seconds = 10
    for i in range(1, seconds + 1):
        queue.put(f'Seconds left: {seconds + 1 - i}')
        time.sleep(1)
    queue.put('Starting task')
    # place a sentinel to tell the reading part
    # that it can stop
    queue.put('done')
    # do the task, this will run it in the same thread
    # so it won't block the main thread
    do_task()


# function to update the label that shows the users how many seconds left
def update_label(queue):
    try:
        # since block=False it will raise an exception
        # if nothing is in queue
        data = queue.get(block=False)
    except Empty:  # therefore except it and simply pass
        pass
    else:
        # if no error was raised check if data is sentinel,
        # if it is, stop this loop and enable the button (if needed)
        if data == 'done':
            button.config(state='normal')
            return
        # otherwise just update the label with data in the queue
        label.config(text=data)
    finally:
        # and (almost) no matter what happens (nothing much should) loop this again
        root.after(100, update_label, queue)


# basic tkinter setup
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

button = Button(root, text='Start countdown', command=start_countdown)
button.pack(expand=True)

label = Label(root)
label.pack(expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I do find it hard to understand the queue concept, so I accepted the other simpler answer.

Comment: @BillyCao you just put something in the queue and then take out of it, almost like a list, anyhow this is still more complex than the other answer